# cppcms on cygwin, build error when trying to compile

Tags: gcc, cygwin, cppcms

cpp:

```
#include <cppcms/application.h>
#include <cppcms/applications_pool.h>
#include <cppcms/service.h>
#include <cppcms/http_response.h>
#include <iostream>

class my_hello_world : public cppcms::application {
public:
    my_hello_world(cppcms::service &srv) :
        cppcms::application(srv)
    {
    }
    virtual void main(std::string url);
};

void my_hello_world::main(std::string /*url*/)
{
    response().out()<<
        "<html>\n"
        "<body>\n"
        "  <h1>Hello World</h1>\n"
        "</body>\n"
        "</html>\n";
}

int main(int argc,char ** argv)
{
    try {
        cppcms::service srv(argc,argv);
        srv.applications_pool().mount(cppcms::applications_factory<my_hello_world>());
        srv.run();
    }
    catch(std::exception const &e) {
        std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
/* End of code */
```

### Makefile:

```
LIBS=-l/home/C5021090/cppcms/cppcms -l/home/C5021090/cppcms/booster


all: hello

hello: hello.cpp
$(CXX) -O2 -Wall -g hello.cpp -o hello ${LIBS}

clean:
rm -fr hello hello.exe cppcms_rundir
```

---

When i try to complile on cygwin i am getting bellow error:

```
$ make
g++ -O2 -Wall -g hello.cpp -o hello -l/home/C5021090/cppcms/cppcms -l/home/C5021090/cppcms/booster
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/C5021090/cppcms/cppcms
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/C5021090/cppcms/booster
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:7: recipe for target `hello' failed
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

The same thing is working fine on Ubuntu linux, I am not pretty much sure with Cygwin, i guess it is due to the corresponding dll file, but i didnot find it any where, I appreciate your help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your two libraries are not built; `cppcms` and `booster`. Build them *in Cygwin* and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

> LIBS=-l/home/C5021090/cppcms/cppcms -l/home/C5021090/cppcms/booster

This is not how the -l flag works. You give -l the *name* of the library:

```
LIBS=-lcppcms -lbooster
```

The linker will look for files called libcppcms.a and libbooster.a

To tell the linker where to find those files, you use the -L option:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/home/C5021090/cppcms
```

and a link step like this:

```
hello: hello.cpp
        $(CXX) -O2 -Wall -g ${LDFLAGS} hello.cpp -o hello ${LIBS}
```